# Matching the width of the React Navigation header components bottom shadow/border with the bottom tabs border-top width

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

My goal right now is to match the React Navigation bottom tabs top border width to be the same width as the top header. For some reason, I can't get the width exactly and I'm not sure if it's width or shadow at this point. Any context as to how I should approach this will be much appreciated.

This is what I currently have as far as styling for the bottom tabs.

```
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        tabBarStyle: {
          borderTopWidth: 0.3,
          backgroundColor: brand.colors.background,
        },
      }}
    >
```

This is what it looks like with a border-top width of 0.3

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following styles are used in the `@react-navigation/elements` package for the `Header` component. I tried them but found that the color might still be off. You could try playing around with the opacity to match the color you prefer.

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    ...Platform.select({
      android: {
        elevation: 4,
      },
      ios: {
        shadowOpacity: 0.85,
        shadowRadius: 0,
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        },
      },
      default: {
        borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
      },
    }),
  },
});
```

See [HeaderBackground.tsx](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/elements/src/Header/HeaderBackground.tsx#L36-L56) on their GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I was able to accomplish a very similar border by setting the shadowRadius to 0.85 and border top width to 0.